# Is there a way to create a mail merge that automatically emails people with a list that meets a given criteria?

Tags: excel, email, ms-word, mailmerge

I am being sent an Excel spreadsheet with a list of students. I am trying to get a mail merge so that it will take a list of students and send that sub-list to their teacher, via email.

An example will look something like this:

`Dave Smith  |   7SF`
`Josie Davis |   7GE`
`Will Jones  |   7SF`

How can I create a mail merge that will select all students from 7SF and send that sub-list to their teacher?

I have tried to create the lists dynamically in the mail merge by using the spreadsheet as a directory (which worked), but it will not let me send the document via email that way. The only other way I can think to do it is to create separate emails manually and copy and paste the sub-lists in, which is what I am trying to avoid by using mail merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DATABASE field in a normal ‘letter’ mailmerge main document and a macro to drive the process. An outline of this approach can be found at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/many-to-one-email-merge-using-tables/8bce1798-fbe8-41f9-a121-1996c14dca5d

Alternatively, if you're using an Excel workbook with a separate table with just a single instance of each of the grouping criteria (e.g. (teacher names and, in the student worksheet, the same teacher names appear against each student) a DATABASE field in a normal ‘letter’ mailmerge main document could be used without the need for a macro. An outline of this approach can be found at:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/mail-merge-to-a-word-table-on-a-single-page/4edb4654-27e0-47d2-bd5f-8642e46fa103

If you don't like doing that kind of development work, you may want to try one of the Many-to-One Mail Merge add-ins, from:

- Graham Mayor at https://www.gmayor.com/ManyToOne.htm ; or
- Doug Robbins at https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=5AEDCB43615E886B&id=5AEDCB43615E886B!566